# Ubuntu server trouble with command-line prompts

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface

I bought VPS with ubuntu 12.04 server minimal. When I logged in, there is very simple command line by default. 
How install full-function command-line with prompt and etc?

Comment: Why do you think it is not functional? What functionality do you expect? What shell are you using?

Comment: as example, auto completion by tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `sh` or something installed. Do this:

```
apt-get install bash bash-completion command-not-found
```

After change the default shell for you user:

```
usermod -s /bin/bash USERNAME
```

Comment: You should re-login after this.